# Select distinct will not work in Apache Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running the below code to define the case class:

```
scala> case class AadharDetails (DateType: Int, Registrar: String,PrivateAgency: String, State: String, District: String, SubDistrict :String, PinCode: Int, Gender: String, Age: Int, AadharGenerated : Int, Rejected: Int, MobileNo: Int,email_id: Int)
```

defined class AadharDetails

Creating a DataFrame using the case class

```
scala> val df = spark.read.textFile("/home/anil/spark-2.0.2-bin-   hadoop2.6/aadhaar_data.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(attributes=>AadharDetails (attributes(0).trim.toInt, attributes(1), attributes(2), attributes(3), attributes(4), attributes(5), attributes(6).trim.toInt, attributes(7),attributes(8).trim.toInt, attributes(9).trim.toInt, attributes(10).trim.toInt, attributes(11).trim.toInt, attributes(12).trim.toInt)).toDF()

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [DateType: int, Registrar: string ... 11 more fields]

scala> df.printSchema()
root
|-- DateType: integer (nullable = true)
|-- Registrar: string (nullable = true)
|-- PrivateAgency: string (nullable = true)
|-- State: string (nullable = true)
|-- District: string (nullable = true)
|-- SubDistrict: string (nullable = true)
|-- PinCode: integer (nullable = true)
|-- Gender: string (nullable = true)
|-- Age: integer (nullable = true)
|-- AadharGenerated: integer (nullable = true)
|-- Rejected: integer (nullable = true)
|-- MobileNo: integer (nullable = true)
|-- email_id: integer (nullable = true)


 df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")


scala> spark.sql("select distinct DateType from data").show()
**Will throw an error**, please let me know why distinct does not work here..!!
```

Sample Data:
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Delhi,South Delhi,Defence Colony,110025,F,49,1,0,0,1

20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Delhi,South Delhi,Defence Colony,110025,F,65,1,0,0,0
[image]

Comment: What error do you see? can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala attached the stacktrace error snapshot.

Comment: As it clearly shows you are trying to convert the String value "Others" to Int, Your data contains Others in the field that you expected Int.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Thank you, I've corrected the Datatype and it worked fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This may happens due to incompatible datatype in column DateTypevalues. It may contains nulls or string which is not interpreted as a valid Integer representation:

You may get error for dataframe show as well.
`scala> df.show()`

Check your source data to confirm the issue of datatype mismatch.